# CORS и кастомные заголовки

Tags: javascript, php, cors

Пытаюсь сделать асинхронный запрос с адреса https://domain.com на https://domain.com:8888/handler

```js
fetch('https://domain.com:8888/handler', {
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include',
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        "X-USER-ADDRESS": 'data string'
    }
})
```

Но каждый раз получаю корс ошибку `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing error: PreflightMissingAllowOriginHeader`

От бэкенда приходять заголовки

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://domain.com
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-USER-ADDRESS
```

Ну тоесть ошибка когда я делаю запрос с сайта на тот же сайт но только с другим портом и при этом отправляю кастомный заголок. Возможно я что-то делаю не так или все таки с одного ресурса на другой нельзя отсылать кастомные заголовки?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: @AlexeyTen пробовал, всеравно получал ошибку.

Comment: Что попробовал? Отвечать на OPTIONS? Как? Код?